# Recommendation for rotating proxy service for large scale scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, http-proxy

So Situation is following, I have multi-threaded python script on server, which should run 3000 request in parallel with 3000 different IPs, 200 times on one run. after that process will be repeated in every 15-20 minutes. I found stormproxy for rotating proxy service but they can't handle such a big ip pool.

**if you can recommend anything please help me out here...**

Comment: Are you building a botnet?

Comment: nope, it looks like that, basically I need to scrape 600 000 url and I am getting detected when I am trying to scrape everything in 15 20 minutes with multi-threading, that's why I want the type of service which will give me 3000 different ips. to scrape 200 url for per ip.